# Angular Material bind button type dynamically

Tags: angular, button, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material in my project. I want to set the button type dynamically based on a variable. I tried something like the following:

```js
export class ButtonComponent {
  type: 'simple' | 'raised' | 'stroked' | 'flat' | 'icon' | 'fab' | 'mini-fab' = 'simple";
}
```

And in the HTML

```html
<button [mat-button]="type === 'simple'" [mat-raised-button]="type === 'raised'">
  Text goes here 
</button>
```

But I get the following error:

> Can't bind to 'mat-button' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Although I have imported MatButtonModule in my module.ts

I appreciate your time and thank you all in advance.

Comment: I have created a **feature request** with the **Angular Material team** to seek **native support for dynamically setting attributes** like `mat-fab`. To ensure this request gains the necessary visibility and consideration, I kindly invite the community to help by upvoting it. Your support in this matter would be greatly appreciated: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/28292.

Answer (score 4):

**For Angular Material >= 15**

I have prepared a component that renders a mat button depending on the given parameters. You can specify type and color from the available material palette.

*my-button.component.html*:

```
<button
  mat-button
  [disabled]="disabled"
  [color]="color"
  [ngClass]="{
    'mat-mdc-button mat-mdc-raised-button': type === 'raised',
    'mdc-button--outlined mat-mdc-outlined-button': type === 'stroked',
    'mat-mdc-unelevated-button': type === 'flat',
    'mat-mdc-menu-item mdc-list-item': type === 'menu'
  }"
>
  <span>{{ text }}</span>
</button>
```

*my-button.component.ts*:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-button',
  templateUrl: './my-button.component.html'
})
export class MyButtonComponent {
  @Input() text: string = "";
  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
  @Input() color: 'primary' | 'accent' | 'warn' = 'primary';
  @Input() type: 'raised' | 'stroked' | 'flat' | 'menu' = 'raised';

  @Output() click: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
}
```

and finally usage:

```
<app-my-button
  text="Click me!"
  color="warn"
  type="stroked"
></app-my-button>
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: While this response offers a practical solution, it doesn't address the actual question, which involves dynamically setting attributes rather than choosing from existing static CSS classes. I've experimented with this using a directive, attempting to switch between "mat-fab" and "mini-fab" by dynamically setting these attributes. However, it seems that the timing of attribute setting is inadequate, resulting in no visible changes. Is there an elegant solution for this issue? Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import **MatButtonModule** to the module that contains your component:

`import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';`

Then if you want to apply element attributes dynamically, you can do it with:

```
<button [attr['mat-button']]="type === 'simple' ? '' : null">
  Text goes here 
</button>
```

Comment: It worked with me but after changing it to the following:

<button [attr.mat-button]="type === 'simple' ? '' : null">
  Text goes here 
</button>

The attribute is applied using this approach, but unfortunately, some Angular Material classes that depend on the attribute are not applied using this way =(. But once again, thank you for your answer.

Comment: That attribute is a directive. When it is applied it does what it supposed to do with the host element (f.ex. apply styling). I really don't know what you need apart of what you described in your question.

Comment: What you probably need is to create a `<button>` with attribute. Because if there is already a button in DOM without directive applied and you apply it later, it will be just an attribute (code from Directive will not be executed). So wrap button with `**ngIf` and place button inside

Comment: What about `mat-fab`? It's a Material Button that doesn't use the `mat-button` prefix. In this case, the "Material Button Type" is set "semi-dynamically". Not all Material Buttons will have the mat-button prefix, and a static list is required. Additionally, what if I want to change the UI library later? That wouldn't be so easy then.

Answer (score 0):

I made this work via ngClass:

```
<button [ngClass]="{
  'mat-button': type === 'simple',
  'mat-raised-button': type === 'raised'
}">Text goes here</button>
```